# Cypress GitHub Actions Build Fails with "Cannot find module" Error

Tags: npm, automation, cypress

I'm setting up Cypress tests in a GitHub Actions workflow, but I'm encountering an error during the build process. This is running correctly on my local machine. When I run npm run build, I receive the following error message:

`[!] Error: Cannot find module '/home/runner/work/CucumberE2E/CucumberE2E/rollup.config.js' imported from /home/runner/work/CucumberE2E/CucumberE2E/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js`

I'm using the Cypress GitHub Action cypress-io/github-action@v6 in my workflow, and I've encountered this issue. I've also tried updating my dependencies and changing the configuration file, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

[cypress-io/github-action](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action) uses the lockfile in the repository to install. If you are using npm, then the lockfile is `package-lock.json` (see [README > Installation](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#installation)).

The most probable reason for your error is that the lockfile is incorrect. To test, you can run `npm ci` locally.

Make sure that you have committed a working lockfile to the repository.

If these hints do not help, then please post your `package.json` and your `*.yml` workflow.